# npm cant install @bit/formidablelabs.react-animations.rotate-in-up-left

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Why is this package not installed?

error :

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@bit%2fformidablelabs.react-animations.rotate-in-up-left - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@bit/formidablelabs.react-animations.rotate-in-up-left@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     c:\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-24T11_19_43_813Z-debug.log
```

page : https://bit.dev/formidablelabs/react-animations/rotate-in-up-left

Comment: Refer to [Configuring bit registry](https://docs.bit.dev/docs/installing-components#configuring-bit-registry) in the docs. **1)** You need to firstly run the following command via your CLI: `npm config set @bit:registry https://node.bit.dev` **2)** Then run `npm i @bit/formidablelabs.react-animations.rotate-in-up-left`

Comment: Did you get a resolution for this? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @SonamAhuja  Yes, I should have registered at https://node.bit.dev